# How to run NUnit tests after deploy on deployed project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, continuous-integration, nunit, teamcity, web-deployment

Is there any way to run Nunit tests on deployed project?
Like after project has been deployed I have to run tests against the project on a deployed environment (because part of functionality can be run only on deployed environment due to the special access policy)

Comment: The answer depends very much on how your are deploying your project and to what environment. Can you edit your question and add more specifics?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run Nunit tests using teamcity on deployed site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35106395/run-nunit-tests-using-teamcity-on-deployed-site)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to run Nunit tests on deployed project?

Normally NUnit is used to write unit tests against separate small functionalities of your application. If you want to run tests against a deployed version of your application then we are talking about integration tests. There are many different tools that can be used to test your running application. One of them is [`Sikuli`](http://www.sikuli.org/). Alternatively if you want to keep using a .NET unit testing platform but firing requests against a real web server you can checkout [`SpecFlow`](http://www.specflow.org/). But no matter which tool you decide to use, you should be ready to write integration tests which are very different in nature compared to your unit tests.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to run tests writen for Nunit against a deployed environment.
You need a way to configure your tests according to the environment to test.

The type of test: unit tests, integration tests, functional tests, system tests etc. is independent from the technology you use to run them. NUnit is a technology to execute tests and gather their results. It has probably been architectured thinking about unit tests, but you can even implement your system tests with it.